# Comparing statsmodel predictions with actual y-values (indexing issue)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, statsmodels

Objective: I would like to calculate the test error for predictions made by a fitted multivariate linear regression model.

Problem: Here is my code. It is intended to fit a linear regression model to training data, and then predict y-values (price) based on X_test variables:

```
X.insert(0, 'constant', 1)   # insert constant column
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
lm_sm = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()

y_pred = pd.DataFrame()   # dataframe for predictions vs actual y-values
y_pred['predictions'] = lm_sm.predict(X_test)

print y_test.sort_index().head()
print y_pred.sort_index().head()
```

The code outputs the following:

```
       price
6   257500.0
17  485000.0
23  252700.0
25  233000.0
26  937000.0
     predictions
0  509428.615367
1  324403.584917
2  477385.431339
3  484962.235105
4  827039.820936
```

Comparing predicted and actual price, this is obviously not right. The `predict()` method does not retain the indexes from my train/test split. So when I compare the predicted prices to actual prices, I can't be sure I'm comparing the right values.

The only solution I've thought of (and I'm not sure if this is right thinking) is to sort X_test when making the prediction, i.e. `y_pred['predictions'] = lm_sm.predict(X_test.sort_index())`. The predictions look a little more aligned with my expectations (note this is a first linear regression / benchmark so no feature engineering has been applied yet):

```
       price
6   257500.0
12  310000.0
18  189000.0
25  233000.0
29  719000.0
     predictions
0  259985.788272
1  590648.478023
2  339621.126287
3  316402.199424
4  635513.611634
```

I would then perform the test error calculation based on these sorted dataframes. Is this right? Is there a cleaner way to do this? A method I don't know about? Any help/thoughts would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually don't think there's anything wrong with the ordering. The mixed-up indices of `y_test`, when compared to the clean indices of `y_pred`, are the source of confusion.

When you use `train_test_split` on your dataset `(X, y)`, it's obviously going to shuffle things around, which is why `y_test` has a shuffled subset of indices.

When you do `lm_sm.predict(X_test)`, the output is a plain numpy array. It's not a pandas object with an index, so that index info is already lost. Plus, in your code, you store the results in a new `y_pred` dataframe. And in that fresh `y_pred`, the indices will be a fresh auto-increment: 0, 1, 2 ...

So just don't use `sort_index()`, and you can be sure that `y_pred` as you have it will line up with `X_test` and `y_test`.

EDIT. Hopefully this illustrates things better.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((60, 3)))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((60, 1)))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

print(X_test)
```

The test set's features:

```
           0         1         2
2   0.547993  0.479149  0.495539
48  0.332964  0.857635  0.501391
23  0.380500  0.377257  0.088766
35  0.045725  0.432096  0.239523
52  0.254861  0.207215  0.985722
37  0.099525  0.205250  0.054000
22  0.426227  0.253524  0.336110
43  0.716443  0.006443  0.423447
49  0.146820  0.803366  0.390921
6   0.127666  0.848561  0.936604
46  0.303034  0.548064  0.852688
33  0.516726  0.977396  0.829725
```

And the test set's targets with `print(y_test)`:

```
           0
2   0.123253
48  0.494307
23  0.312021
35  0.939558
52  0.958955
37  0.681215
22  0.181427
43  0.907552
49  0.589316
6   0.613305
46  0.947220
33  0.696609
```

Indices are shuffled, but they agree. Now do:

```
lm_sm = OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()
y_pred = pd.DataFrame()   # dataframe for predictions vs actual y-values
y_pred['predictions'] = lm_sm.predict(X_test)

# Print this directly
print(lm_sm.predict(X_test))
```

Last line is just a plain numpy array:

```
[ 0.44549342  0.44973765  0.24465328  0.17840542  0.42329909  0.09567253
  0.30675321  0.38496281  0.33836597  0.49959203  0.47488055  0.63751567]
```

And when you look at the new `y_pred` dataframe, the indices are a fresh 0, 1, 2 ... `print(y_pred)`

```
    predictions
0      0.445493
1      0.449738
2      0.244653
3      0.178405
4      0.423299
5      0.095673
6      0.306753
7      0.384963
8      0.338366
9      0.499592
10     0.474881
11     0.637516
```

You might have been surprised that these indices don't match those of `y_test`, but as I showed, the `predict()` function returns a plain numpy array, and there's nothing connecting the resulting `y_pred` to the original indices anymore. Nevertheless, you can be sure that everything is aligned.

Comment: `predict` in recent versions of statsmodels should return a pandas Series with the appropriate index if the provided exog has an index. There were some bugs in special cases during the transition but the indexing of the predict return should be a correctly indexed pandas.Series in statsmodels 0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `train_test_split` now has optional parameter `shuffle=False` to avoid shuffling.  That should solve your problem with alignments in the df.